# Gather single rows from multiple tables in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have several tables in Microsoft Access 2013, all of which follow the same format of:

ID  |   Object   |  Person 1  |  Person 2  |  Person 3  |

ID  |   String   |   Yes/No   |   Yes/No   |   Yes/No   |

What I would like to do is make a query where I put in a string value for each table and it prints out the entire row, with each string getting its own row, so it looks like:

ID  Number  | Object        | Person 1...
Table 1 ID   | Table 1 String | Table 1 Yes/No...

Table 2 ID   | Table 2 String | Table 2 Yes/No...

Every time I try, though, it puts all the data into one extremely long row that's impossible to look at. All of my searching has only turned up people trying to do the exact opposite of what I'm doing, though, so I must be missing something obvious. Any tips?

Comment: Well...that's hardly a normal form of data - so you're not likely to find good examples to go by

Comment: Build a report and use its grouping and sorting functionality.

Comment: @June7, reports seem to only give me all of the rows from one table, they won't allow me to take only a single row from each table. When I try to take data from multiple tables or delete the rows I don't care about, nothing shows up.

Comment: How many tables are involved? How are they related?

Comment: @June7, there are ten tables, each about a different category. They all have a column of object names and columns of people (always the same people in the same order) and whether or not they have that object.

Comment: Should be one table with another field for category. A UNION query can mimic that one table structure.